# Adding additional rows to data based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a project to create a template that uses one of my regular exports and changes the way the data is structured. I've attached a sample spreadsheet below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFo_VpdeXpWkpLqMNnCBAT_93rx_JCjG508VsEwMoL4/edit?usp=sharing

The "Source Data" tab is my export, it's a list of orders where rows are repeated for each unique product that the customer has purchased. The Order Numbers are repeated for as many rows that the order has.

I'm trying to add additional row(s) to each order on my "Corrected Data" tab based on conditions and perform a calculation that would change the data that the additional row outputs.

The conditions / rules are as follows.

1. To add any additional rows the "Shipping Cost" of the order (column O) must be > 0
2. If an order has all products with a Tax Class of > 0 then 1 additional row should be added. The Order Number needs to be the same, the "Product Code" (column J) should have "TAXABLE-SHIPPING", the Product Name (column K) should be "Taxable Shipping" and the "Product Price" (column T) needs the following calculation: ROUNDDOWN((ShippingCost/(100+TaxClass)*100),2). Every other column can remain blank.
3. If an order has all products with a Tax Class of 0 then 1 additional row should be added. The Order Number needs to be the same, the "Product Code" (column J) should have "ZERORATED-SHIPPING", the Product Name (column L) should be "Zero Rated Shipping" and the "Product Price (column T) should be the same as the "Shipping Cost".
4. If the order has a mixture of Tax Classes then 2 additional rows should be added. The Order Number needs to be the same for both rows, one row should have "Zero Rated"and "ZERORATED-SHIPPING" in the Product Name/Code Columns and the other row should have "Taxable Shipping" and "TAXABLE-SHIPPING". respectively.

   The "Product Price" on these two rows needs to do the following calculations and apply to their respective rows.

   1. ZERORATED: ROUNDDOWN(((SUM(Product Prices that have 0 Tax Class)/Order Subtotal)*Shipping Cost),2)
   2. TAXABLE: ROUNDUP(((((SUM(Product Prices that are > 0 Tax Class)/Order Subtotal)*Shipping Cost)/(100+Tax Class)*100),2)

So far, I've managed to get this working with a bit of help to the point where 1 additional row is being added when the Shipping Cost is > 0. This is only with a few select columns rather than the whole dataset. This can be seen in the "Partial Solution" tab.

I don't even know where to begin with the 2nd additional row with multiple tax classes, or how to wrap the calculations into that.

I appreciate that this one is quite lengthy and difficult, perhaps formula isn't the best solution here but I was hoping a single cell array formula would be able to do this. Any help at all pointing me in the right direction would be hugely appreciated! <3

Comment: I've added a Desired Results tab, Order - 7740692 doesn't have an additional row due to a 0 shipping cost

Order - 7740693 is entirely zero rated, the desired results are in cell T6
All green orders have all products at 20 Tax Class, their calculations I've highlighted in green
The final order 7740683 colored in orange is the mixed tax class order where desired calculations are marked in T31 and T32 - thanks for taking a look :)